# React Native image handling

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an app I'm working on using React Native. I'm trying to build a contact list with image thumbnails pulled from my backend. There are several hundreds of contacts in my list so the total size for all the thumbnails is quite high. What is the proper procedure for handling this scenario? I'm guessing I should only load the images one by one as needed when browsing through the list. Caching images can also help but how do I know if my cached image has become stale?

Any suggestions for libraries are also appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know how many contacts you'll have, and are your list items fixed/known height? If so `FlatList` will provide some useful helpers.